# Convert Objective-C dictionary definition to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, translate

I'm using the [CRToast](https://github.com/cruffenach/CRToast) class for an app and in the documentation, it says to declare the options as:

```
NSDictionary *options = @{
                          kCRToastTextKey : @"Hello World!",
                          kCRToastTextAlignmentKey : @(NSTextAlignmentCenter),
                          kCRToastBackgroundColorKey : [UIColor redColor],
                          kCRToastAnimationInTypeKey : @(CRToastAnimationTypeGravity),
                          kCRToastAnimationOutTypeKey : @(CRToastAnimationTypeGravity),
                          kCRToastAnimationInDirectionKey : @(CRToastAnimationDirectionLeft),
                          kCRToastAnimationOutDirectionKey : @(CRToastAnimationDirectionRight)
                          };
```

I've mostly converted the code to swift, except for the first key-value pair.  I'm getting a syntax error that says "Type 'NSString!' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'".  My swift translation is:

```
var options = [kCRToastTextKey :"Hello World!",
            kCRToastTextAlignmentKey : NSTextAlignment.Center,
            kCRToastBackgroundColorKey : UIColor.redColor(),
            kCRToastAnimationInTypeKey : CRToastAnimationType.Gravity,
            kCRToastAnimationOutTypeKey : CRToastAnimationType.Gravity,
            kCRToastAnimationInDirectionKey : CRToastAnimationDirection.Left,
            kCRToastAnimationOutDirectionKey : CRToastAnimationDirection.Right]
```

UPDATE:
I tried adding a line of code above the options declaration to make an NSString

```
let text:NSString = "Hello World!"
```

And then used

```
var options = [kCRToastTextKey :text,
```

The hashable message went away, now I'm getting "'NSString' is not convertible to 'CRToastAnimationDirection'"

Comment: What happens if you remove the first entry?

Comment: Then wouldn't the banner have no text?  And that gives me an error that "'NSTextAlignment' is not convertible to 'CRToastAnimatonDirection'"

Answer (score 0):

I think the  kCRToastKeys are not compliant to being hashable types,

try this:

```
var options = [kCRToastTextKey as String):"Hello World!",
        kCRToastTextAlignmentKey as String: NSTextAlignment.Center,
        kCRToastBackgroundColorKey as String : UIColor.redColor(),
        kCRToastAnimationInTypeKey as String : CRToastAnimationType.Gravity,
        kCRToastAnimationOutTypeKey as String : CRToastAnimationType.Gravity,
        kCRToastAnimationInDirectionKey as String : CRToastAnimationDirection.Left,
        kCRToastAnimationOutDirectionKey as String : CRToastAnimationDirection.Right]
```

Comment: that just makes an error on every line, the compiler thinks each "key as String" needs to be followed by a comma

Answer (score 0):

You can use rawValue like this answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27034350

Should be something like this.

```
let options:[NSObject:AnyObject] = [
    kCRToastTextKey: "Hi!",
    kCRToastTextAlignmentKey: NSTextAlignment.Center.rawValue,
    kCRToastBackgroundColorKey: UIColor.blueColor(),
    kCRToastAnimationInTypeKey: CRToastAnimationType.Gravity.rawValue,
    kCRToastAnimationOutTypeKey: CRToastAnimationType.Gravity.rawValue,
    kCRToastAnimationInDirectionKey: CRToastAnimationDirection.Left.rawValue,
    kCRToastAnimationOutDirectionKey: CRToastAnimationDirection.Right.rawValue
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This was answered on github [here](https://github.com/cruffenach/CRToast/issues/111#issuecomment-62817462). Use:

```
var options: NSDictionary = [
    kCRToastTextKey : "Hello World!",
    kCRToastTextAlignmentKey : NSTextAlignment.Center.rawValue,
    kCRToastBackgroundColorKey : UIColor.redColor(),
    kCRToastAnimationInTypeKey : CRToastAnimationType.Gravity.rawValue,
    kCRToastAnimationOutTypeKey : CRToastAnimationType.Gravity.rawValue,
    kCRToastAnimationInDirectionKey : CRToastAnimationDirection.Left.rawValue,
    kCRToastAnimationOutDirectionKey : CRToastAnimationDirection.Right.rawValue
]
```

Same poster I believe. The answer was only slightly different than ckang's.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Good Point Kampai. Thank you for being gentle, im new. I edited my response.