# In Swift, how can I use setValueForKey to set the textAlignment property of an object?

Tags: dynamic, reflection, swift

Let's say we define an object like this:

```
let object: AnyObject = {

    var result = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 50))
    result.text = "First Text"
    result.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    return result
}()
```

For this example, I explicitly created a `UILabel`, but in my actual project I don't know what type of object is created, so I'm just treating the result as `AnyObject` for this example. The object is just a standard UILabel with text of "First Text" on a blue background, default aligned to the left.

In this example case, I know that this object is actually a `UILabel`, so I know I can change it's properties like this:

```
(object as UILabel).text = "Second Text"
```

And now I've changed the text. But in my actual project, I don't know that my object is a `UILabel`, so I can't just do the `(object as UILabel)` trick, because it's not always a `UILabel`. My way around that is using `setValueForKey`. After checking that my object has a member called "text" using `respondsToSelector` (not shown in this example), I can change the text this way:

```
object.setValue("Third Text", forKey: "text")
```

Now, if I wanted to change the `textAlignment` of the object, after checking that the object does indeed have a member called `textAlignment`, I'd want to do something like this:

```
object.setValue(NSTextAlignment.Center, forKey: "textAlignment")
```

Doing this results in an error though:

```
Type 'NSTextAlignment' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'
```

I ran into something similar while trying this approach with setting the `frame`, because it didn't like the `CGRect` type, but I was able to get around it by converting the `CGRect` to an `NSValue`. However, I can't find a way to fix it for `enum` types like `NSTextAlignment`.

Anybody know how I can achieve my goal here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use raw value NSTextAlignment.Center.rawValue

```
 object.setValue(NSTextAlignment.Center.rawValue, forKey: "textAlignment")
```

Comment: This is perfect! I had looked at rawValue a little bit, but I didn't realize I could use it this was. I was trying to use it to invoke a `NSTextAlignment`, but I was falling right back into the position of passing an enum into setValueForKey. This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to declare a protocol with the properties you are interested in, and then extend the types you want to work with to adopt that protocol. IF that would work for you in this case, it seems safer.

Comment: While the protocol approach seems safer, the fact of the matter is that I don't know what properties will be used, because I don't know what objects are being used. Everything is happening dynamically, at runtime, so I really wouldn't be able to implement any static cold for the properties themselves. The furthest I'm able to go is implementing conversion functions from the dynamic values (string literals) to whatever types the attribute they are trying to set is.